# Select most specific row in MySQL with wildcards

Tags: mysql, select, wildcard

I have a table `ABR` with three columns: two lookup values, `A` and `B` and a result `Result`. I want the result to be returned given `A` and `B`

But, for some values of `A`, column `B` can be a wildcard. In that case I want the most specific row.

**I can't seem to figure out the MySQL statement though** - I found one, but it was 7 lines long and had 5 `=` and two `IF`'s, there must be a better way.

```
A   B   Result
1   *   First
2   *   Second
2   1   Third
2   2   Fourth
3   *   Fifth

Example wanted results:
A=1, B=5 -> First
A=1, B=0 -> First
A=2, B=2 -> Fourth
A=2, B=4 -> Second
A=3, B=7 -> Fifth
```

Do notice that the column values can change later: we can add extra rows for A and B, or remove values. Hardcoding stuff in the SQL is not acceptable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT Result
    FROM ABR
    WHERE A = @LookupA
        AND (B = @LookupB OR B = '*')
    ORDER BY B DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Yes, this would work. But I'm joining this table on another series of join, and the ORDER-BY-LIMIT-1 would throw off my GROUP-BY I have already. Or maybe I should put this one in a subquery then, and join against the subquery result?

Comment: @Konerak: Sounds like the subquery would work. You'd have to try it and see.